# Removing letters from strings in nested array and converting them to integer

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this:

```
[["a3"], ["b3"], ["c7", "c9"]]
```

I need to remove the letter from the strings and convert them into integers. I need:

```
[[3], [3], [7, 9]]
```

I tried:

```
 [["a3"], ["b3"], ["c7", "c9"]].each do |a| 
   a.map do |string| 
     puts leave_num = string.slice!(0) 
     puts leave_num.to_i
   end  
 end
```

but I am sure there is a nicer way.

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [["a3"], ["b3"], ["c7", "c9"]]

a.map { |r| r.map { |e| e[/\d+/].to_i } }
# => [[3], [3], [7, 9]]
```

Comment: @GaganGami: That is correct, However, the OP did not post such an example. What he did say was "remove the letter", which by English grammar implies there will be only one letter, and I took it to mean that all the cases will consist of one letter followed by an integer representation (and silently discarded the case where a single letter is in the middle of a number, as I cannot see a use case for such a thing). Should the OP clarify that your interpretation is, in fact, the correct one, I will amend my answer.

Comment: I agree with you. I just assume the case for more letters. You are right at your place.

Comment: The OP's code (`slice!(0)`) does not imply such case either

Comment: @Stefan & Amadan : Ok I misunderstood and think for other cases also. I have removed my comments. Your point is correct

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this can be:

```
a = [["a3"], ["b3"], ["c7", "c9"]]
a.map { |b| b.map { |c| c.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i }}
# => [[3], [3], [7, 9]]
```

Basically I'm going through each element and returning integers using regex.

Comment: True, but how you concluded `d5d54d` should return `554` ? You are making assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your code:

```
string[0]  = ''
puts string  # instead puts leave_num = string.slice!(0)  
puts string.to_i  # instead puts leave_num.to_i
```

another option:

```
a.map{|e| e.map{|n| n[1..-1].to_i}}
 #=> [[3], [3], [7, 9]]
```

If your array elements has more letters like `"d58as9a"` so for such case try this although @Amadan and @Shivam's answers are correct:

```
a = [["a3"], ["b3"], ["c7", "c9"], ["d58as9a", "d5d54d"] ]
 > a.map{|e| e.map{|n| n.scan(/\d/).join('').to_i}}
 => [[3], [3], [7, 9], [589, 554]]
```

**Note:** This will extract all digits from string.